# xmodmap: set Alt keys to simultaneously behave as normal Alt and as level chooser

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'd like to know if it's possible to set both <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys to behave simultaneously as Alt and as the third-level chooser (AltGr). I've mapped several special characters I often use under some combination of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>*char*</kbd> and so would like to be able to use both the left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys as the third-level choosers, but if I map both keys to AltGr I lose the functionality of Alt, which I also need.

Comment: Suppose it is possible. Then you press Alt+o, and you have Alt+o as a shortcut that opens a new terminal, whereas AltGr+o produces ó. How would your system decide which event should be triggered? Or should it trigger both?

Comment: So it's unlikely there is a built-in way for this in `xmodmap`. I suppose having the system trigger both would make the most sense: special characters by their own are almost never used as shortcuts in any application, so having them trigger together with a particular Alt+char combination shouldn't make any issues. What would be the most efficient way of doing this though? Doesn't mapping the combination to e.g. some `xdotool` command in a particular WM/shortcut daemon also forfeit the combination trigger being applied on its own in a particular application?

Comment: Yes, Xmodmap is for more simple and straightforward remaps. I doubt one could avoid the XKB rabbit hole for such a complex task. I also agree that Xdotool will prove fruitless here. [xkeyboard-config](https://www.mankier.com/7/xkeyboard-config) does not list an option like that either. :(

Comment: This is very much possible. In fact I had somewhat of a similar (but more in depth) thing running for CTRL some time ago, which I based it on its KEY_UP event, i.e. if I clicked on CTRL and let go it , and then pressed another  key within a specific interval it would register as CTRL+KEY allowing for one hand presses of CTRL+P etc. Your situation may be even simpler because you are mainly looking to copy the behavior of AltGr onto left ALT. However, what would you like to happen when Alt+Key and AltGr+Key do have different functionalities?

Comment: Also an even simpler option is to switch between AltGr and ALT for the left ALT may be a double/triple press of a given special key. I also used that to switch between kleyboards for different languages ,( for example triple press of left shift to switch between regular and Hebrew when learning it on Duo)

Comment: To clarify, for maximum convenience I would like *both* ALT keys to simultaneously have both AltGr and ALT functionality. As mentioned in the previous comments, I guess there is no way for this other than having the system trigger both events when a particular key combination is pressed (so both the special character and the combination itself), though I suppose they can be mapped separately to the key press and release triggers or to single and double press triggers, as you mentioned. Could you provide an answer with an example of the relevant code for this?